# Ag-Grid Angular Cell Renderer inject CellRendererService

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, cellrenderer

I want to implement a CellRenderer that can show/hide the cell it is attached to (let's call it `ShowHideCellRenderer`).

I want this cell renderer to take a cell renderer (`innerCellRenderer`) as a parameter which defines how the cell is rendered if it is visible.

In the ag-grid repository on github there is the `GroupCellRenderer` which also uses an inner cell renderer:

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid/src/ts/rendering/cellRenderers/groupCellRenderer.ts#L245

```
let rendererPromise:Promise<ICellRendererComp>;
if (params.fullWidth == true) {
    rendererPromise = this.cellRendererService.useFullWidthGroupRowInnerCellRenderer(this.eValue, params);
} else {
    rendererPromise = this.cellRendererService.useInnerCellRenderer(this.params.colDef.cellRendererParams, columnToUse.getColDef(), this.eValue, params);
}

// retain a reference to the created renderer - we'll use this later for cleanup (in destroy)
if (rendererPromise) {
    rendererPromise.then((value:ICellRendererComp) => {
        this.innerCellRenderer = value;
    })
}
```

But to do the same I need to somehow inject the `CellRendererService` into my CellRenderer.

As I am using Angular for creation of the CellRenderer the `@Autowired` decorator does not seem to work.

```
export class ShowHideCellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    @Autowired('cellRendererService')
    private cellRendererService: CellRendererService;

    public agInit(params: any): void {
        console.log(this.cellRendererService); // undefined
    }
}
```

Doos somebody know how to inject the `CellRendererService` into my angular cell renderer? Or do you have an idea how to implement an inner cell renderer in another way?

Comment: Is you `cellRendererService` defined as `@Injectable()`?

Comment: @Paritosh No it's not my own service. It is from the ag-grid source. I think they use soom kind of alternative DI system: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid/src/ts/rendering/cellRendererService.ts

Comment: Not clear what exactly you wanna to get?
Own `cellRenderer`? Is it a trouble?
`I want to implement a CellRenderer that can show/hide the cell it is attached`
could you please extend your requirements.
`cellRenderer` - can be used to handle UI perspective of cell